# Google Places API Autocomplete Input/Output Language

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, maps, google-places-api

I have a question regarding the google places autocomplete API.

A user in germany should be able to search in german showing `Berlin, Deutschland` in his

input field, which I realize using the `language` parameter in my js file.

Furthermore I would google to return the english names so I can store them in my database

(`Berlin, Germany`).

Is this possible? Or should I just save the `LAT/LNG`? Because it is not recommended to save the

`Unique ID`, Google says.

Comment: It's not allowed to store anything(except for a short period)

Comment: I know, its only for a short period to improve my google maps api performance. see terms : (i) limited amounts of Content for the purpose of improving the performance of your Maps API Implementation if you do so temporarily (and in no event for more than 30 calendar days), securely, and in a manner that does not permit use of the Content outside of the Service; It only works with google autocomplete and not outside.

Comment: store the `reference`